# Set completely disabled/untouchable hours ranges

Tags: javascript, html, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler, fullcalendar-5

I am testing the functionality of this widget and now I've faced with situation when I must to create a vertical Resource view for the day work scheduler.

```
    _calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
        initialView: 'resourceTimeGridDay',
        dayMaxEvents: true,
        dayMinWidth: 130,
        allDaySlot: false,
        nowIndicator: true,
        slotMinTime: '10:00:00',
        slotMaxTime: '22:00:00',
        slotDuration: '00:15:00',
        slotLabelInterval: '01:00:00',
        slotLabelFormat: {
            hour: '2-digit',
            minute: '2-digit'
        },
        editable: true,
        selectable: true,
        selectMirror: true,
        displayEventTime: true,
        displayEventEnd: true,
        eventResizableFromStart: true,
        eventResourceEditable: true
    });
    _calendar.render();
```

So - this is trivial example of the initial desirable appearance of this widget on the page.
And now i can also to add Events for ResourceA|B|C|D... which randomly cover ranges of business hours for simplicity of the example.
For example, from 12 to 13:30, then from 15:45 to 16:45, then from 18:15 to 18:45.

And only now is the question time)))
How to add - in dynamics! - NON-working hours ranges - which should be completely inaccessible for selection/interaction! You should not be able to click/select/resize them with the mouse (as it can be done with ordinary events, placed earlier), you cannot intersect with them when changing the time range of events adjacent to them, already set earlier, in the schedule. Those it must be an unbreakable barrier/stronghold among all the other events in the daily routine.
HOW to achieve that?

Comment: Does https://fullcalendar.io/docs/business-hours meet your needs? Perhaps combined with https://fullcalendar.io/docs/businessHours-per-resource ? If you need more flexibility (e.g. because the time ranges for the non-business hours are not consistent week-by-week) then I suggest using https://fullcalendar.io/docs/background-events . You can then make it so users cannot select time periods covered by background events (e.g. the inverse of the example at https://fullcalendar.io/docs/selectOverlap).

Comment: P.S. Remember that all client-side code, including fullCalendar options, can be overridden, removed, bypassed or subverted by a malicious user. Ultimately the only "unbreakable" way to stop people adding events on those times is to add server-side validation, so that your server code checks that the event time is allowed before adding it to your database. But it's certainly possible to use fullCalendar's functionality to make the user experience easier so that the vast majority of "normal" users don't add events where they shouldn't and don't have to wait for the server to reject them.

Comment: @ADyson - I've read about the business-hours - BUT I do not have information about them on the stage of creating the Calendar object. ALL actions with Calendar are performing "on-the-fly". Like that - in this current second we found out that we must to show new Resource - new teacher - which has lessons in 2 time ranges: [12:15-13:00] && [15:45-16:45]. And then the clock "ticked" 14:00 we suddenly found out that she has nonworking hours in range: [14:30-15:15]. This use-case definitely not covering by the logic of business hours. Because she has full day busyness))) from 10:00 and till 18:00.

Comment: background events(BE) were also tested and they shown complete incompetence... I can add them "on-the-fly" - but they are not completely non-interacting objects with other events. For ex. I set BE for 10:00 - 11:00. After that I set real event - real lesson from 11:00 and till 11:45. For now - al is ok)) BUT remember! all real events - are re-sizable! And admin for mistake decided to move upper range of the event from 11:00 to 10:45. And it will succeed in this task! BE even with flag 'selectOverlap' - will not be an obstacle to moving the upper border of the time range for my real event.

Comment: YES, the documentation says that it seems like it should not be so, but reality shows that it is not.
That is why I wrote that I am waiting for a response from those who ALREADY went through all these stages and were able to come up with a real implementation of the task of creating non-working periods of time.

Comment: Please be aware that resizing and dragging is not the same as selecting. Selecting is only done when selecting an empty area for creating a new event. There are separate callbacks for handling resizing and dragging. So "selectOverlap" is not relevant when resizing. This section of the documentation covers that behaviour: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-dragging-resizing

Comment: I could not find any callbacks/flags/...whatever else... - which can be used for protecting of some hours ranges for selection/intersection/dragging/resizing - once and for all... Again - what's why I put my question here - to hope that someone already could do this "hard trick".

Comment: "I could not find"...I know, that's why I gave you a link to where you can find them. For dragging & resizing, it's the ones in the "CONTROL" section of the last link I gave you, which are likely to be relevant to your situation.

Comment: Similarly for selections, in https://fullcalendar.io/docs/date-clicking-selecting you can find selectOverlap, selectConstraint and selectAllow - again, any/all of these can be used to help you achieve your goal, possibly in combination with background events. It's then up to you to determine the exact code you will need to implement your exact rules. if you get stuck on a specific part of the implementation - any bug you encounter, or something particular you are unsure of, post the code you have written so far into your question, and explain the specific difficulty, then we can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, thanks to @ADyson - I was able to find all pieces of info...

1. Create "on-the-fly" barrier-event:

```
let newEvent = new Object();
newEvent.start = new Date('2020-12-14T10:00:00');
newEvent.end = new Date('2020-12-14T12:00:00');
newEvent.resourceId = resId; /* for which teacher i must add the NONwrk.hours vault */
newEvent.display = 'background'; /* the MAIN feature - this event is a background event */
newEvent.overlap = false; /* prevents this event from being dragged/resized over other events. 
                          Also prevents other events from being dragged/resized over this event */
_calendar.addEvent(newEvent);
```

2. Let's configure the _calendar object with one more control flag, along with the others that I have already used in the code:

```
  selectOverlap: function(event) {
    return event.display !== 'background'; /* the user will not be allowed to select periods of time 
                                                 that intersect with bg.events on the calendar */
  },
```

And I will get what I wanted to get)))